# Cannot download RDS snapshot as .sql file(s)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a snapshot of an RDS instance, and I would like to download/export as .sql files.
However, on the AWS console, there are strangely missing options:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Is there a clear way to download the snapshot to my local machine from the console?

Comment: I don't use RDS, but I am pretty sure a snapshot is not SQL. Instead it is some sort of binary that can reconstituted as a new RDS instance, hence the Migrate snapshot option. For more info see [Snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreateSnapshot.html). I suspect what you are looking for is a data/schema dump of the instance.

Answer (score 1):

RDS snapshots are effectively [snapshots of the EBS volumes](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/database/amazon-rds-snapshot-restore-and-recovery-demystified/) (virtual hard drives) that store your database data, and are made on a level higher than the database level.

To dump your data in SQL format, restore the snapshot into an RDS instance and use the [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) utility.

Alternatively, you can [export the data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ExportSnapshot.html#USER_ExportSnapshot.Exporting) from the snapshot to S3 in Parquet format.

Under the hood, AWS will run a transient RDS instance, restore the snapshot onto the EBS volume attached to this instance and run the database-native export task that will dump your data to S3.

Comment: so maybe just better to take a `pg_dump` of the original DB instead of taking a snapshot at all, innit?

Comment: @AlexanderMills you didn't specify that you had an instance running.

Comment: well, I am taking a snapshot of an instance, not sure what else I could take a snapshot of. You got my upvote either way.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: you didn't specify that it was you taking the snapshot either. For all I know you might have inherited it from a rich uncle. I'm a simple man: I'm asked about the snapshot, I'm answering about the snapshot. Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: @AlexanderMills "maybe just better to take a pg_dump of the original DB instead of taking a snapshot at all, innit?" Taking an RDS snapshot allows you to quickly restore or create a new RDS server from the existing snapshot. AWS will also take automated snapshots for you which serve as backups of your database. RDS Snapshots exist for a very good reason, just not the specific reason you are trying to use them for at this moment.

Comment: A snapshot is questionable as a backup. If the storage fails (e.g., the file system becomes corrupted), your "backup" is gone as well. I know what I say is unrelated to the question, but I would want an alternative backup, for example a `pg_dump`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: this kind of snapshot is somewhat similar to LVM snapshots, which happen on block level, deeper than filesystems. Once a snapshot has initiated, it's frozen, and further filesystem corruptions can't affect it. Subsequent snapshots are incremental, they only copy what would be called "COW space blocks" in LVM parlance. Of course `pg_dump` has its uses and you can totally use it as well, it's just not something AWS provides as a service.

Comment: @Quassnoi I don't share your belief that a software bug in the COW file system cannot affect a snapshot.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: on EBS (and LVM), COW happens on the block level, below any filesystems. Once you start the snapshot, it's frozen, set in stone. Any filesystem software bug that had happened before that moment, had already happened. Any filesystem software bug that happens after the snapshot, won't affect it, because it will by definition happen in the COW space which is not a part of the snapshot. There might be bugs in EBS itself, but if the storage itself fails, `pg_dump` will be of little help either.

Comment: @Quassnoi When I say "file system", I also mean the piece of software that knows which block belongs to which snapshot. Color me paranoid, but I don't trust a backup unless it is stored on different storage than the database.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: oh, once it's been frozen, the frozen image is copied to S3, in the background. This is called "pending state". Once the copy completes, it goes to "available state". By this time, it's stored completely in S3. I've seen snapshots fail because EBS volumes failed (physically) during the copy, but I'm yet to see one which would fail to restore from S3 after it had saved completely.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: of course the same strategy is implemented with LVM snapshots on prem: you freeze the filesystem then copy it elsewhere. I thought it was obvious.

Comment: @Quassnoi Now that sounds much better; thanks for the clarification. I don't use Amazon's services, so I didn't know.